# Does Windows Sharepoint Services install an application or a framework or both?

Tags: wss-3.0

I can't tell what it does.  Does it install web pages and a framework for me to use?

I installed it.  It does install a website for you to administer the services.  From there I'll read on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a  simplistic view/answer - WSS-3.0 is a framework for you to use.  The full blown Sharepoint is built on top of it.